# xcode 7 playground error

Tags: ios-simulator, ios9, xcode7

When I'm testing code on a new playground on Xcode 7 beta 2 I permanently get this error message:

```
No matching device (3B67EE98-FFB1-4371-B307-F80ADA4BB609) in set at /Users/home/Library/Developer/XCPGDevices
```

[image: Screenshot for error]

I have restarted the project, created a new single view project but the playground won't compile or print/display the console on the right side. Is someone actually being able to create new projects with Xcode 7 beta 2?
Finally fixed it with last beta version, even a bit slow, but it works fine.

Comment: Update: When I try to edit or type in a new sentence on any existing or new playground file, it displays the alert message mentioned above. Dismissed by pressing OK. Start typing and it shows up again. This is the current issue.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was connecting a device, and then I restarted XCode 7.  I went back and opened up my playground.  Everything worked for me after that.